# Software updates stuck downloading after 15.04 upgrade

Tags: apt, updates, 15.04

I recently upgraded my system from 14.10 to the new version (I know, my second mistake, the first one was the upgrade to 14.10), 15.04. Let's say that since I did that, last Friday, I didn't notice major drawbacks (except for some strange lock-screen issue) until today.

Yesterday evening I forgot to shut down the computer and today after I logged in I started to see some strange increased CPU usage. There was a `/usr/lib/apt/methods/http` process that took 100% of the CPU constantly. Seeing this, I thought doing a software update (graphically) would terminate the process, but instead I got a message like apt-get cannot exit, or something like that. I thought perhaps some other process locked apt, so I tried to unlock it by removing the lock files `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/lock` but nothing changed, the process was still running.

Then I thought perhaps a reboot will fix the issue, so I rebooted the computer. After the reboot the `/usr/lib/apt/methods/http` process was indeed gone, so I tried updating the software sources manually to see what was going on. When I ran `apt-get update` I noticed that at the end the update is stuck with a line such as `100% [15 Packages 25.6 GB/25.6 GB 100%]`, where the total amount of data (the size in GB) is increasing, it does not stop. I had to interrupt the command because I didn't know what it was doing.

What should be the problem ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: Something may be wrong with your software sources. Carefully go through `/etc/apt/sources.list` and everything in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` for `deb` statements that look suspicious, or edit your question and add all the `deb` statements.

Comment: my sources.list contains only official sources, everything else was discarded when I did the upgrade

Comment: One way of debugging this would be to comment out all the `deb` lines except one, and see where the `apt-get update` command gets stuck. That includes any lines in the `sources.list.d` folder. To narrow it down, do a "binary search" - comment the first half, if that gets stuck  the harmful `deb` line must be in the second half, etc.

Comment: I had to disable the universe, multiverse and restricted repositories in order for the update to finish. I hope they'll fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. It seems as there are some problems with the repositories for universe and multiverse. After I removed all of these sources the update runs again without any issue.

Greetings

Comment: I disabled universe, multiverse and also restricted and now the update finished. I hope they'll fix this issue.